# Update android database

Tags: android

I am trying to update a value in my sqlite Android database. I am using:

```
    public void updateName(int id,
                String name) {
            String update = "UPDATE STUDENT SET IS_name = " + "'" + name + "'"
                    + " WHERE ID = " + id;
            database.rawQuery(update , null);
    }
```

But the database is not updated. Any help please?

Comment: The raw query is only committed if you actually to something with the returned Cursor, like cursor.moveToFirst() or something. But just for updating use execSQL (see Samir Mangroliya's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
db.execSQL(update);
```

Like,,

```
String update = "UPDATE STUDENT SET IS_name = '"+ name +"' WHERE ID = " + id;
db.execSQL(update);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any selection args into your raw query.  You'll need to create a String array and add the name and id values into it (in that order).  Then pass the array as the second argument to your `rawQuery` instead of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Use following function to update database.

```
public void updateTipsDetails(int id,String name)
{
    try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TIPS, name);



        db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, id + "=" + COLUMN_ID, null);
        db.close(); 

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```